# Fishpig Wordpress Extension not working for multiple store Magento 2

Tags: magento2, wordpress, blog

I have installed Fishpig Wordpress extension for Magento 2.It is working fine for my europe store.But for my other store it shows me 404 page.Can you guys just guide me how to configure the fishpig for multiple store view?

Please check screenshot below,

This is my wordpress database configuration,

[image]

Working Fine for the europe store.

[image]

Showing me 404 page for deutschland store.

[image]

Please let me know if you guys need any additional information.How to fix this issue.Please... its an urgent.
Thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: Is there any solution? Please let me know.Thanks

Comment: Hi @Sunny did you find any solution?